# How to convert MODIS 500m resolution to 0.05 degree resolution in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, modis, resolution

I am checking MODIS GPP product in google earth engine and I noticed that the spatial resolution is not matched with our product. Our product is 0.05 degree resolution but, in case of the MODIS GPP (MOD17A2), the spatial resolution is 500m. How can I change 500m to 0.05 degree in GEE and can I check the data in GEE map? In addition, I want to check the point-scale comparison as below.

```
var ROI = /* color: #d63000 */ee.Geometry.Point([127.2505, 38.2013]); // site.10
    
    var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD17A2H')
                      .filter(ee.Filter.date('2018-01-01', '2020-12-31'));
                      
                      
    var gppVis = {
      min: 0.0,
      max: 600.0,
      palette: ['bbe029', '0a9501', '074b03'],
    };
    // Map.addLayer(dataset, falseColorVis, 'False Color');
    //var s2_regpp = dataset.map(gpp);
    var gpp = dataset.select('Gpp');
    var add_regpp = function(dataset){
      //Create band variables
      var gpp = dataset.select('Gpp');
      var gpp2 = gpp.rename('regpp');
        return dataset.addBands(gpp2);
    };
    var s2_regpp = dataset.map(add_regpp)
    
    var series2WM = ui.Chart.image.doySeriesByYear(
        s2_regpp, "regpp", ROI, ee.Reducer.mean(), 500);
    print(series2WM );
    
    //Map.setCenter(6.746, 46.529, 2);
    Map.addLayer(gpp, gppVis, 'GPP');
```